# Error when compiling in gcc, expected identifier '(' before 'double'

Tags: c, gcc, include

I'm trying to compile the attached C code with

> gcc -Wall -o nesta.o nesta.c

but I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> nesta.c: At top level:
> nesta.c:1004:15: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘double’
> void restrict(double *coarse, double *fine,int imaxc,int jmaxc,int imaxf,int jmaxf)
> ```

As a side note, this is an old C program that used to work back in 1997.

[nesta.c](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e1IN8IheejOoeyp-Ftk6URKm_RPWxB0t)
[praxis.h](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m5p3h91G2_wVcPqBfwi1pnuZcq9eVur5)

Comment: Please show your code here directly, as a [mcve].

Comment: You've not granted permission in Google Drive to access the source you want us to help you with.  This is not going to work.  Please copy (a subset of) the source into the question.  But, but the time you've created the MCVE, you may well have resolved your problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to use a function name `restrict`, judging from the error message.

C99 introduced that as a keyword.

You'll need to force C90 mode in your compiler in the (very) short term; in the medium term, you'll need to rename the function so it doesn't match a keyword.

This is why the standards committee are reluctant to add keywords; they break existing working code (but at least it is a noisy breakage).  It's not unreasonable that the code worked in 1997, before the C99 standard was finalized — it's likewise not unreasonable that it no longer compiles; `restrict` has been part of the standard for nearly 20 years now.